# Drag and drop to simulate swipe on an Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I normally don't ask questions, since I can usually find my answer by researching, but I am stuck on this one. Here is what I am trying to do. I am trying to simulate a finger swipe, but with the mouse. I have an image, with an image map spot where the would be a link. I need this link to be clickable when doing a normal click. I first tried using mousedown and mouseup events. This worked perfect as far as firing my swipe functions, but my issue was that I could not stop the click event from firing when the drag was released over the link. I then tried using ondragstart and ondragend, and this was able to stop the click from firing on drag, but now my swipe functions are not firing. I also need to keep the image from actually being dragged, which I why I did "return false" on the dragstart event. I also am trying to implement a way to detect if the mouse was dragged a certain distance, to account for minor mouse movement on a normal click.
  Am I on the right track here? Is there a better way of doing this? I would appreciate any advice. Here is an example of my code:

html:

```
<div id="imgWrapper">


<img id="thisImage"     src="https://s10.postimg.org/sna4a9pgp/example.png" usemap="#thisMap">
</div>

<map name="thisMap">
<area shape="rect" coords="235,207,406,250" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="thisAlert()" />
</map>
```

and Javascript:

```
var startX = 0;
var startY = 0;
var endX = 0;
var endY = 0;

var thisAlert = function() {
  alert("Link Clicked");
};

document.getElementById('thisImage').ondragstart = function(event) { 
    startX = event.pageX;
    startY = event.pageY;
    return false;
};    

document.getElementById('thisImage').ondragend = function(event) { 
    endX = event.pageX;
    endY = event.pageY;
    alert(endX);
    // Swipe Up
    if (startY - endY > 20) {
      alert("Swipe up");
    };
};
```

Codepen example here: http://codepen.io/Williz/pen/kXQqRB

PS. I am using Jquery also, if that helps.

Comment: I think you were on the right track just using mousedown and mouseup. You just need to `preventDefault` if the mouse traveled more than X pixels, to prevent the link from opening

Comment: I went back to mouseup and mousedown as you suggested, Now everything is working fine in chrome, but I cannot seem to stop the click event in IE. The 2 browsers I need it be compatible with are IE 10+ and chrome. I updated the codepen to show you what I mean. I have also tried stopPropagation() and return false. Any advice?